# encoding format of multilingual text while saving to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have website that save content in various languages. just to display that i have enter to database.

*Suppose i copy a French text in sql server table column it will display correct on my website, but when i try to save it through my website to table then it does not save text in same encoding as before insert method.*

**My question is regarding sql server text encoding format that it use to save such type of multilingual text??**

i want convert my text encoding from website to sql server encoded text.

Is there issue of Collation. [Database behind a Multilingual User Interface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10005/database-behind-a-multilingual-user-interface)

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to use `nvarchar(n)` type column. You can then store UCS2 data in that column. The width of the column can be decided based on the data.